# How do I make this align from left to right instead of up and down

Tags: html, css

How do I make this format left to right And not up and down?
I have tried `text-align: center;`
Thanks!

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="side">
      <h2>Email</h2>
      <h5>email@gmail.com</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="side">
        <h2>Email</h2>
        <h5>email@gmail.com</h5>
      </div>
</div>
```

This is the result I am getting currently.
[image: Current Result]

Comment: You are missing a closing tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
div {float: left;}
div:after {content: ""; display: table; clear: both;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="row">
    <div class="side">
      <h2>Email</h2>
      <h5>email@gmail.com</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="side">
        <h2>Email</h2>
        <h5>email@gmail.com</h5>
      </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This formats everything that way. How do I not make Other things on my page go the the right also

Comment: Use the new code which I edited in the answer.

Comment: If you find this useful, please upvote as well, I am new to this community. :)

Comment: I will! It seems to be pushing my title over as well.. I only want this to happen the code shown

Answer (score -1):

Use `text-right` class to right align text.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12 text-right">
    <h2>Email</h2>
    <h5>email@gmail.com</h5>
  </div>
  <div class="col-12 text-right">
    <h2>Email</h2>
    <h5>email@gmail.com</h5>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I believe there is an easier way to align text other than importing an entire CSS library.